# How to make a bind to Ctrl Key for toggling snapping on/off

Tags: shortcut, snapping

I would like to make a bind to Ctrl Key for snapping on/off. When I press Ctrl - snapping should be toggled on/off. Is it possible to make?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use solely a modifier for a shortcut, plus there already is a shortcut to toggle this: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

If you still want to, you can change this in the User Preferences.

If you open the user preferences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, and switch to the *Input* tab, you can search by shortcut (Click the dropdown next to the search box and select *Key-Binding*) to find entries containing "shift tab":

[image]

Now, find the entry under 3D view:

[image]

And press where it says *Shift Tab* and press the keys you want to bind.